# Array out of bounds error- Raygun crash log doesn't specify line within class

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift3, crash-reports

Recently I have been seeing a lot of array out of bounds errors but Raygun crash log doesn't specify a line within a class that could help pinpoint the source of the error. Without this info, it's difficult to debug. Any ideas?

[image: Raygun crash report 1]

[image: Raygun crash report 2]

Comment: to get help with this issue you would likely need to provide the code for your tableview. From the error it appears that the existingCellForRowAtIndexPath function is trying to access a cell which is in fact no longer existing. This isn't a common error so it's likely to do with the tableView implementation

Comment: @Scriptable thanks! I have implemented many tableviews throughout the project. I'm not sure which tableview implementation this could be referencing. Is there a way to figure that out?